# Usage of RxFloatingActionButton

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-binding

In trying to adapt some standard Android programming to `RxBinding` I'm stuck on `RxFloatingActionButton`. The class has one method, `visibility(view)`, which returns a `Consumer<Boolean>`. Yet the Javadoc says "The created observable keeps a strong reference to {@code view}." Where is the "created observable"? 
A very brief usage example would help greatly. I assume that to detect clicks on the FAB, I would use the normal View click observable?

Comment: could you elaborate on your question?
I don't seem to find any RxFloatingActionButton in Rx-Binding libraries.
Would you please add the dependencies snippet?

Comment: This: `com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.support.design.widget.RxFloatingActionButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fabEnabledObservable.subscribe(RxFloatingActionButton.visibility(fab), /*handle error*/)
```

`fabEnabledObservable` is `Observable<Boolean>` which decides if the button should be shown or hidden.

Yes for clicks `RxView.clicks()`